# How to set nginx to use static and dynamic page on the same domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, deployment, puma

I have a Ruby on Rails application, using Nginx webserver with HTTPS running with success in a specific domain (e.g. https://testing.com).

Now, I purchased a landing page template (HTML and JS only) and I need to set it up in the same domain.

Being more specific, what I need is:

1. https://testing.com/  -> renders landing page template
2. https://testing.com/* -> renders RoR application

As far as I do not have much knowledge on Nginx configuration, here it's my nginx current configuration:

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/var/www/poseidon/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name testing.com www.testing.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-testing.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name testing.com;

    root /var/www/poseidon/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on; # Optional
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
}
```

I uploaded the landing page nginx configuration and I tried something like, but I had no success:

```
location /* {
    root /var/www/landingtesting.com;
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated!